# Laravel Protected Route With same Model

Tags: laravel-5, roles, laravel-middleware

I changed the users table and put a field called "role" and was wondering if it is possible to use middleware to protect routes only by checking this field.
The table users:
[image]

I wnated something like this:
If user role == 0

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {});
```

If user role == 1

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:customers'], function () {});
```

However with the same table

Comment: The `auth` middleware already has a parameter for the guard used, e.g. `auth:web`, so you need a custom middleware to do that with a role.

Comment: I tried to use middleware for authentication, but I can only do this with two tables, one for users and one that creates another table of customer calls, for example. What I want is to do this same check only with the users table.

Comment: make a new middleware that checks that field on the authenticated user, you can pass parameters to the middleware

Comment: Thanks, folks. I do this with: if(Auth::check()){
            if($request->user()->role != 0){
                return redirect('/');
            }
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new middleware:

```
php artisan make:middleware CustomerMiddleware
```

The function handle in the new middleware:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::check()){
        if($request->user()->role != 0){
            return redirect('/');
        }
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

The protected route in app/Http/Kernel.php

```
'CustomerMiddleware' => \App\Http\Middleware\CustomerMiddleware::class,
```

The group routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'CustomerMiddleware'], function () {  });
```